# Changing paragraph alignment of word document through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I Have excel workbook which maintains data of my customers Like address & Due amount. I am writing a VBA code in excel which will generate letter to each of the customer for the due amounts.  I cannot use mailmerge because of the complexity of the letter. I am using following codes to add paragraphs

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
wrdDoc.content.InsertAfter "----------"
wrdDoc.content.InsertParagraphAfter
```

Now I need to change alignment of paragraphs. The paragraphs in body of letter are to be justified while some paragraphs like subject line are to be center aligned. I tried this code but its not working

1.

```
wrdDoc.Paragraphs(8).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

also

2.

```
wrdDoc.Paragraphs(8).Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

What is the correct way doing this?

Regards
Shekhar

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

objselection.Paragraphs.Alignment = 3

Numbers:

3 Justify
2 Center
1 Right Justify

Comment: This worked for me but I found that 1 = Center. My code is `WordApp.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1` -- to change paragraph alignment to center for the selection, iterated in a for each loop.